# Skype 4.3 video problem Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: video, skype

i want to make an video call with my contacts but there is a problem I am not able to solve..

I followed this manual:

```
    First you will need to make sure you have libv4l-0 installed.

    If you have installed Ubuntu restricted extras then you should already have it if not open Software Centre and install Ubuntu restricted extras from there.

    Once this is done open a Terminal and copy and paste the following command

    sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop

    After you have provided your password a text editor will open. Line 4 should look like this

    Exec=skype

    Replace with this text

    Exec=bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype'

    Save and exit the text editor and close the terminal. Now you can open Skype and test your webcam via 'options' then 'video devices'
```

I can see the video in Skype settings -> video .. in there works everything ok ..

but when i want to make a call, there is a CAM_icon which I cannot enable, so it is only "voice-call" ..

Do you have any ideas?

webcam: logitech c170

Answer (score 1):

solution:

it is ok now... my fault guys ... it works only when the other person accept the call :)))) after the call was estabilished, webcam works perfect :) thank you

webcam: logitech c170

Answer (score -2):

The steps you need to follow, as ~Fuhrer707 details, are:

Install User Agent Overrider Firefox add-on (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-gb/firefox/addon/user-agent-overrider/)
Set the user agent to Windows / Edge
Restart Firefox
Go to web.skype.com
Allow access to microphone and notifications
Make a Skype test call and adjust audio levels based on the recording

Comment: I thought the web version of Skype under Ubuntu (with the user-agent workaround) only supports voice calls, not video?